# iOS ARC memory warning

Tags: ios, memory, automatic-ref-counting, warnings

I create a app in iOS with ARC, when use for a little surfing between screens memory up down correct but after some use is presented messages "received warning mermory" and crash!

What is the problem?

Cumps

Answer (score 0):

It could be any number of things. Just because you use ARC doesn't mean you won't ever have memory warnings, it just means you don't have to manually increase and decrease reference counts.

You need to watch out for things like retain cycles. Don't keep strong pointers to objects when it's not necessary. Be sure to dereference strong pointers when appropriate.

I suggest looking into the basics of how ARC works.

Comment: Yes I've walked to see the situation, but the problem should not be there. When I order from one controller to another I think this does not closed.

I show message in dealloc method and message not show.

My code to transition is this:

VCMain *viewNew = [[VCMain alloc]initWithNibName:nil :bundle:nil];
viewNew.globalVariable = globalVariable;
[self presentViewController:viewNew animated:NO completion:nil];